# Detached search bar as action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design

In my app, I'd like to implement an action bar that looks like the one found in Google Play or Maps, that is, a search bar which also has a hamburger menu.

Similar to this:

[image: A screenshot from Google Maps which demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve]
<sub>(source: [softpedia-static.com](http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/news2/Google-Rolls-Out-Maps-9-0-for-Android-with-Materials-Design-UI-Screenshot-Tour-464402-5.jpg))</sub>

Notice the search bar at the top. How would I be able to replicate this?

Comment: You can use a toolbar for this or you can make this using a layout design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this library while searching for persistent search. I believe this is what you are looking for.

> [Android Persistent Search Library](https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use a `Toolbar` with the attributes:

```
android:layout_marginLeft
android:layout_marginRight
android:layout_marginTop
android:layout_marginBottom
```

set to some `dp` (8 or 12 might be a good try).